# Get the width-height of my screen and modify it to fit any device

Tags: javascript, android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an **android Phonegap** app and i really need to get the width and height of my screen and i need to modify it to fit any android devices that i try..so
I need to find the device-width of the mobile device. Although we can specify the content

Here is my css code
i need to modify the width and the height within the screen sizes played by the device

```
.slide2 {
            width: 300px;
            height : 400px;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-right: 10%;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can try media queries? `@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 640px)`. Look at responsive design on google.

Answer (score 0):

Specify width and height as percentages. This will make it render uniformly on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app-view {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And containing all your elements within div#app-view? Would that not work?